# Can I overwrite an Object that has been Locked() in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a few objects that I'd like to send to the server, but I want to make sure that this is the only thread that moving the data from Stage to Upload.  Is the following code valid in a multithreaded environment?

```
        List<CounterInternal> UploadToServer = new List<CounterInternal>();
        List<CounterInternal> StagingQueue = new List<CounterInternal>();
      lock (this.UploadToServer)
        lock (this.StagingQueue)
        {
            if (UploadToServer.Count == 0)
            {
                UploadToServer = StagingQueue.DoDeepCopyExtensionMethod();
                // is the following line valid given that I have a Lock() on it?
                StagingQueue = new List<CounterInternal>();
            }
        }
      }
```

Comment: You have the code written but took the time to post a question because...you can't locate the F5 button?

Comment: I'm testing it, but am thinking there may be other hidden things that may crop up.  For example, it's feasible that the lock won't take, will disappear after being overwritten, or I'll lose data.  I'm thinking through the edge cases, but since I'm new it's possible I don't know what to ask.  Please don't take the question literally and see my intention...

Comment: I wasn't trying to come across as overly sarcastic. If I did my apologies, I was just saying (and maybe it's how _i learn_) you're 99% of the way there, why not just try it and see? And as @Andy mentioned, [lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) puts a hold on the reference, so not a good idea to be changing it up while it's locked.

Comment: @Brad: As he said, he's asking about edge cases. Perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, yes, but this is a bad idea.  Consider this C# source file:

```
using System;

class Foo {
    static object foo = new object();
    static void Main() {
        lock (foo) {
            foo = new object();
        }

    }
}
```

The `Main()` method will compile to:

```
.method private static  hidebysig
       default void Main ()  cil managed
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2100
    .entrypoint
    // Code size 35 (0x23)
    .maxstack 3
    .locals init (
            object  V_0)
    IL_0000:  ldsfld object Foo::foo
    IL_0005:  stloc.0
    IL_0006:  ldloc.0
    IL_0007:  call void class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Monitor::Enter(object)
    .try { // 0
      IL_000c:  newobj instance void object::'.ctor'()
      IL_0011:  stsfld object Foo::foo
      IL_0016:  leave IL_0022

    } // end .try 0
    finally  { // 0
      IL_001b:  ldloc.0
      IL_001c:  call void class [mscorlib]System.Threading.Monitor::Exit(object)
      IL_0021:  endfinally
    } // end handler 0
    IL_0022:  ret
} // end of method Foo::Main
```

This corresponds to the following source (decompiled by hand):

```
static void Main() {
    object V_0 = foo;
    Monitor.Enter(V_0);
    try {
        foo = new object();
    } finally {
         Monitor.Exit(V_0);
    }
}
```

So the object that is locked on will be stored in a local -- this guarantees that the object's monitor will be released even if the object reference stored in the field is replaced.  There will be no deadlocks created by this technique alone, and any other threads already blocked on `Monitor.Enter()` will continue to block as usual, until this thread releases the lock.

However, any thread that enters this method *after* you have reassigned the object but *before* the active thread releases the lock will be acquiring a lock on the *new* object and hence **there can be two threads in the lock block at the same time.**

A better solution would be to use a separate object and lock on it instead.  I usually use something of the class `System.Object` (or just `object`) since all it is doing is acting as a mutex.  This will allow all threads to lock on the same object, while allowing the other object reference to change.  This is also a useful technique when you need to lock to mutate a value type, which cannot be locked on.

Comment: One day I need to learn how to read and manually do what you did above!  Thanks!  How did you learn to do that?

Comment: To do what? Decompile IL by hand, or just obtain the IL in the first place?

Comment: It's not too hard when you know what the IL opcodes do.  Just read instructions and write out the C# that they correspond to.  For example, the first opcode (`ldsfld`) pushes the value of a static field onto the stack.  The next, `stloc`, pops a value off the stack and stores it in a local.  So it's apparent from that IL sequence that a local is assigned the value stored in a static field.  I don't have enough characters to explain the whole method, but [the OpCodes class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.aspx) would probably be helpful.

Comment: Right now I'm thinking of passing around a single instance of this class.  Would your method still work if I make everything static?

Comment: Of course.  Whether the variables belong to an object or a class doesn't matter much when using this technique.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea.  `lock` operates on a specific instance and you create a new one when you do a `new List<>`.  Another thread could come along and lock the new StagingQueue while another thread is still within what you thought was the locked region.

You should either:

1. `lock` on another instance variable (preferably a `readonly` one), maybe even an `Object` instance that exists purely to be the object that is locked.
2. Modify the algorithm so that it does not create a new instance of `List<>`.  If all you want to do is empty the list, for instance, just call `StagingQueue.Clear()`.